# Intercept CDialog creation

Tags: windows, user-interface, mfc, cdialog

I have a rather large app that displays many different MFC CDialog-derived dialog windows.  All of the dialogs are displayed from a central function that is similar to this:

```
void ShowDialog(CDialog& dlg)
{
  dlg.DoModal();
}
```

Now I need to essentially call a function in every dialog's OnInitDialog method.  It doesn't technically need to be within OnInitDialog, but preferably before the dialog is visible.

The brute force method would be to go through the code and find every last dialog and add the function call to the OnInitDialog method (if it has one, and if it doesn't, add one).  But it seems like there must be a more elegant way...

Note that dlg is not actually a CDialog, but something that derives from it.

Any thoughts, tricks or hacks?  I'm not above patching the message map, but hope to find something cleaner/safer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it is quite easy to do:

```
HHOOK gPrevHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, HookProc, NULL, myGUIThreadID);


LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(NULL != wParam)
    {
         CWPRETSTRUCT* pS = (CWPRETSTRUCT*)lParam;
         if(WM_INITDIALOG == pS->message)
             CallFuncOnWindow(pS->hwnd);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(gPrevHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Probably not the thing to do for a high performance app, but for something that is a simple GUI it works perfectly.  No other code changes required.

Comment: The official term for this is "technical debt".

Comment: This is simply astounding. It would have been quicker to do it the right way! All you had to do was a regex on class.*CDialog and replace CDialog with CMyCommonAncestor. 1 hour absolute tops. And you'll benefit for ever after.

Comment: Except that wouldn't handle all the dialogs that didn't implement an OnInitDialog.  And it wouldn't handle the dialogs that already have a base class and call Base::OnInitDialog in their OnInitDialog.  Any cases that were missed would be bugs.  This is 7 lines of code that won't miss any, doesn't rely on humans to remember to derive future code from the base class, etc.  If this were an 'interception framework' there would be articles written about it :)

Comment: CDialog introduces OnInitDialog. Not calling base OnInitDialog already is a bug. What you have is very poor design. Complex and opaque and needless. You have abandoned KISS for Keep It Complex.

Comment: OnInitDialog is virtual, not pure virtual.  It's not required and silly to call if it does nothing but call the base class.  I fail to see how 7 lines of code is more complex than introducing a new class into an existing class heirarchy and requiring hundreds of lines of changes, most of which the compiler can't verify.

Comment: @DougN Because the next time you need to make a change that applies to all your dialogs you'll be able to do it easily. My code base has a common ancestor for all its dialogs and we have reaped the benefits time and time again.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a common ancestor for all your dialogs, which you seem to imply you have, then you can simply put the code in that common ancestor in a suitable location of your choice. For example `OnInitDialog()` is virtual.

Comment: CDialog is the only common ancestor :(

Comment: @Doug Put a common ancestor in then.

Comment: That's not much different from the brute force "find all OnInitDialog" methods.  I'm hoping for something like redirecting WM_INITDIALOG to a separate function (hooking) or some other trick so I don't have to change all the other code.

Comment: @Doug It's trivial to switch to a common ancestor. Everywhere you descend from CDialog, you interpose your common ancestor. The benefits will be apparent long into the future I can assure you!

Comment: I agree with David. Maybe the amount of work of adding a common ancestor (CMyDialog) is similar to adding the method call to every dialog. But it'll give you a lot of benefits in the future.